# Column Header from Function Result

Tags: sql, function, alias

I have a function that returns dates in a specific format

FormatDate(int PreviousMonths, int Format) returns varchar(100) - E.g. FormatDate(0,2) returns 'June 2011'

But I'm having trouble aliasing the column properly.

A simple example that gives a syntax error is:

```
Select Foo as dbo.FormatDate(0,2) From FooTable
```

How can I alias a column with the result of a function?

Sorry, my question seems to be a bit unclear - here is some additional information:

Table named FooTable consisting of one column named Foo, with 3 rows of data containing 1, 2, 3.

```
Select Foo as dbo.FormatDate(0,2) From FooTable
```

Returns:
June 2011
1
2
3

Thanks,
Dustin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there...

<strike>Select Foo = dbo.FormatDate(0,2) From FooTable</strike>

Or

```
Select dbo.FormatDate(0,2) AS Foo From FooTable
```

Edit:

You can't have dynamic column aliases, especially not per row

You can have the value sent out like this though:

```
Select
   Foo AS SomeValue,
   dbo.FormatDate(0,2) AS SomeName
From FooTable
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your first solution gives a syntax error - it doesn't like the equals sign there. The second solution aliases the Function result as Foo - I'm trying the other way around. I will edit my post with expected sample output. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @Dustin Geile: I always use the 2nd format: was working from (faulty) memory

Comment: You can't have dynamic column aliases: Darn, that's what I was afraid of. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dbo.FormatDate(0,2) as t from FooTable
```

Comment: Sorry, this aliases the column as 't' instead of the function result. I'll edit my post to make my expected output more clear.